# Android : Network timeout while getting response using .net webservice

Tags: android, web-services

I need to import large amount of data (more than 1000 rows) using `.net` webservice,
it shows `"network timeout error"` , resulting approx 200-300 records successfully out of 1000+

What should be the way to import whole data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is likely related that it is taking too long to insert all 1000 rows into the database before the connection timeout expires.

There are 2 ways I can think of to get round this issue.

Either increase the connection timeout, this may not be the best solution however. If you were having a small internet connection problem or the server where the database is located was running slower than normal, you will might end up with some records being inserted but not all of them.

I personally think the best method would be to split the query so it only returns, say 100 rows at a time. I.e. it gets the first 100, inserts them to the database, upon successful completion, retrieve the next 100 records and call the web service to insert that 100 rows, upon success get the next 100 records and so on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome time out problem, you need to implement time outs in your `HttpClient`.

There are two types of time out.

1. Connection Time out : Sets the timeout until a connection is etablished.
2. Session time out : Sets the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.

You need to set time outs like below.

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

//50 secs connection time out
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,50 * 1000); 
//50 secs session time out
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 50 * 1000); 

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```